# Do Legendary resistances from different sources stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, resistance

I am building a level 12 Dragon sorcerer who also happens to be a vampire (as per the optional rule in the MM).

My DM has given us all a legendary item that fits in with our backstory and I have been given the Blue Dragon Mask from the Hoard of the Dragon Queen.

As far as I can tell, I get 3 legendary resistances from being a vampire and 1 from the dragon mask. Is there any reason that the legendary resistances wouldn’t stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Effects of the same name don't stack

Initially, Legendary Resistance was rather solely a monster-only trait, only acquirable by PCs through the relatively rare means of becoming a monster that has this property, eg. a vampire like your character. Because this trait wasn't presumably meant to be available through other sources, there's no special rules regarding it - it's just a normal monster trait as far as the mechanics are concerned.

However, *Rise of Tiamat* does include the artifact Dragon masks that each provide the PC wearing them with one use of Legendary Resistance per day (available for free in [this online supplement](https://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/RiseTiamatSupplementv0.2_Printer.pdf)). This makes it possible to have a Legendary Resistance from being a vampire and from having the mask, but this is a rare edge case without any specific rules attached.

Fortunately, Jeremy Crawford, the lead rules designer of DnD 5e, has resolved the situation with a [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/793866445000089600):

> Effects from game features with the same name never stack.

Therefore, you're limited to using either the one use of Legendary Resistance provided by the mask or the three uses provided by your vampirism - already quite a powerful boon, so I believe this judgment is better for balance than allowing stacking.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling this would be the case but i couldnt find anywhere that explicitly called it out.

Comment: This answer could be improved by just citing the DMG instead of a tweet summarizing the DMG. See [Combining Game Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects)

Answer (score -6):

Nope.

> Multiple instances of resistance or vulnerability that affect the same
>   damage type count as only one instance. For example, if a creature has
>   resistance to fire damage as well as resistance to all nonmagical
>   damage, the damage of a nonmagical fire is reduced by half against the
>   creature, not reduced by three-quarters. PHB 197

Most things don't stack, like advantages. It makes the game simpler and run smoother.

More than that Legendary actions and resistances are DM tools. It is used to make the game more exciting by having the creatures of legend be able to break some sequence of the game because of their power.

The important thing (and fun thing if you let yourself discover it) about roleplaying is making cool things happen and experiencing consequences. Sometimes, those cool things happen to you. Like losing an arm or dying in a fiery explosion. You shouldn't be afraid of exploring cool things by trying to overload a character with advantages.

It sounds like you guys are playing a different kind of game and you should ask your DM.

Have fun, lose an arm.

Comment: SE has a ["Be Nice"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy. Please realize we are all just trying to find the best answer for OP and there is no need to get angry or to be rude.